# Find the index of an element relative to a click function in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following situation below fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ze6wv2e2/

When I click on a "view_larger" class, I am trying to get the index of the ".inner" parent class in reference to the whole page.

For example, if I click on the 2nd view_larger class, The index of ".inner" class should be equal to 1.

This is what I have so far:

```
$(".view_larger").click(function(){
    var classIndex = $(this).parent().index();
    console.log("classIndex");
})
```

I hope this is clear enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use below if you want the index to be based on all the `.inner` elements. Then use the [.index(selector)](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-selector) version, this will give the index of the element based on the element set of the passed selector.

```
var classIndex = $(this).parent().index('.inner');
```

Clicking `hi3` will give you 3 in this case

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u7fu71tc/)

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something simple I was missing!